# Conditional remove adjacent duplicates from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code that removes adjacent duplicates from the `$myArray`

```
<?php
 $myArray = array(
                    0 => 0,
                    1 => 0,
                    2 => 1,
                    5 => 1,
                    6 => 2,
                    7 => 2,
                    8 => 2,
                    9 => 0,
                    10 => 0,
                );

            $previtem= NULL;
            $newArray = array_filter(
                $myArray,
                function ($currentItem) use (&$previtem) {
                    $p = $previtem;
                    $previtem= $currentItem;
                    return $currentItem!== $p ;
                }
            );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

It works perfectly fine, but I have to change a condition bit for value `2`. That means for other values we can pick first occurrence and ignore the others. But for `2`, we need to pick last occurrence and ignore others.

So required output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0 //first occurrence of 0 in $myArray
    [2] => 1 //first occurrence of 1 in $myArray
    [8] => 2 //last occurrence of 2 in the $myArray
    [9] => 0 //first occurrence of 0 in $myArray
)
```

How to modify my code to achieve above result??

In reality I have multidimensional array, but for better explanation I have used single dimensional array here in the question.

**UPDATE**
My actual array is

```
$myArray = array(
        0 => array("Value"=>0, "Tax" => "11.00"),
        1 => array("Value"=>0, "Tax" => "12.00"),
        2 => array("Value"=>1, "Tax" => "13.00"),
        5 => array("Value"=>1, "Tax" => "14.00"),
        6 => array("Value"=>2, "Tax" => "15.00"),
        7 => array("Value"=>2, "Tax" => "16.00"),
        8 => array("Value"=>2, "Tax" => "17.00"),
        9 => array("Value"=>0, "Tax" => "18.00"),
        10 => array("Value"=>0, "Tax" => "19.00"),
    );
```

And my actual code

```
$previtem= NULL;
$newArray = array_filter(
    $myArray,
    function ($currentItem) use (&$previtem) {
        $p["Value"] = $previtem["Value"];
        $previtem["Value"] = $currentItem["Value"];
        return $currentItem["Value"]!== $p["Value"] ;
    }
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
function array_filter($a) {
$na = array();
$first = true;
$p = null;
$wantlast = false;
foreach ($a as $v) {
    if ($wantlast) {
        ($v != $p) ? $na[] = $p: null;
    }
    $wantlast = ($v == 2) ? true : false;
    if (!$wantlast) {
        (($v != $p) || ($first))? $na[] = $v : null;
    }
    $p = $v;
    $first = false;
}
return $na;
}
```

Comment: adjusted to match function name to that used by WatsMyName

Comment: Thanks I will check and let you know

Comment: It changes key which I don't want to change.

Comment: I sorted this out. Thanks for the working solution. I will accept your solution because your solution worked perfectly fine with multidimensional array.

Comment: Thank you. I felt that a stand alone function should better allow you to modify to suit your needs - particularly in light of the fact that your example was a simplified from the real use case - sorting an array.  

In the case of not modifying the key, update the foreach to "foreach (a as $k => $v)" - record the key in the same places, and use it when storing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array(
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 1,
        5 => 1,
        6 => 2,
        7 => 2,
        8 => 2,
        9 => 0,
        10 => 0,
    );

$previtem= NULL;
$newArray = array_filter(
    $myArray,
    function ($currentItem, $key) use (&$previtem,$myArray) {
        $p = $previtem;
        if($currentItem != 2){
            $previtem = $currentItem;
        }else{
            $lastkey = array_search(2,(array_reverse($myArray, true)));
            if($key != $lastkey)
                $currentItem = $previtem;
        }
        return $currentItem!== $p ;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will check this

Comment: What to do in case of multidimensional array?? Like in update in my post above